# PHP - echo missing entries

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a problem.

I have three tables **class_tbl,subject_tbl, and *student_tbl**. class_tbl has 3 columns *"class_id, subject_id, and student_id".* while subject_tbl has 4 columns *"subject_id,subject_name,subject_yr,subject_sem"* and lastly *student_tbl has 2 columns "student_id and student_name".*

class_tbl has these rows:

```
**[class_id || subject_id || student_id]**

|| 1001   ||    2002    || 3003

|| 1002   ||    2003    || 3003

|| 1003   ||    2004    || 3003
```

subject_tbl has 5 rows:

```
**[subject_id ||  subject_name  || subject_yr || subject_sem]**

|| 2002     ||    Math        ||    2010    || 1st

|| 2003     ||   Science      ||    2010    || 1st

|| 2004     ||    History     ||    2010    || 1st

|| 2005     ||      PE        ||    2010    || 1st

|| 2006     || Social Studies ||    2010    || 1st
```

student_tbl has 1 row: depending on the number of students actually

```
**[student_id || student_name]**

||   3003   ||  John Parker
```

The goal here is that the query will echo the last 2 subjects which is PE and Social Studies so that I can insert them to class_tbl. The echo is telling me that I dont have 2 entries for the 2 subject during that semester and school year. The query will not echo the subjects which are already in the entries of class_tbl which are Math,Science, and History.
How do I query and echo the missing subjects of that semester and year? I really cant come up with any idea. Help tnx!

The code here displays all subjects of that school_yr and semester.

```
            if (isset ($db1)&&$db1!=""){


            }

            <?php

                $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
                $sem = $_POST['sem'];
                $yr = $_POST['yr'];

                $list = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                    FROM
                                    class_tbl 
                                    LEFT JOIN
                                    subject_tbl
                                    ON
                                    class_tbl.subject_id = subject_tbl.subject ID
                                    WHERE
                                    student_id = '$student_id'
                                    OR
                                    subject_sem = '$sem' 
                                    OR
                                    subject_yr = '$yr' 
                                    ORDER BY 
                                    subject_id asc");

                while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list))
                {
                echo $row_list['subject_id'];

                if($row_list['subject_id']==$db1){echo "selected"; }

                echo $row_list['subject_name'];

                }
```

The example output would be:

You have 2 missing subjects "PE and Social Studies."

Comment: please structure it a little more human-readable (for example make things bold or italic)

Comment: if you used http://sqlfiddle.com/, then helping you would be easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    subject_tbl a
        LEFT JOIN class_tbl b
            ON  a.subject_ID = b.subject_ID AND
                a.subject_yr = 2010 AND
                a.subject_sem = '1st' AND
                b.student_ID = 3003
WHERE   b.subject_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f28c/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╦════════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ SUBJECT_ID ║  SUBJECT_NAME  ║ SUBJECT_YR ║ SUBJECT_SEM ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║       2005 ║ PE             ║       2010 ║ 1st         ║
║       2006 ║ Social Studies ║       2010 ║ 1st         ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Many tnx to u ... last  question. may I ask if its ok, what does "a.*" in SELECT and class_tbl "b" stands for? are they supposed to be tables? Sory...

Comment: `a and b` are called alias of table `subject_tbl` and `class_tbl`, respectively. `a.*` mean that select all columns from table `subject_tbl`.

Comment: you're welcome `:)` alias are helpful when you have longer table names.

Comment: hey mate, it did work somehow but why is the query showing duplicates although some subjects belong to a different semester and school yr. Even though I specified the semester and school year. For example, History has 2nd semester with 2010 school year and another History for 1st semester with 2011 school year. The echo displays the 2 same name entries.

Comment: how about adding distinct, example `SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM...`

Comment: already tried that one mate, hehehe. still desame output. The rows are duplicating. what if we provide aliases for the columns?

Comment: can you give more sample records which show duplicate records based on the query? willing to help :)

Comment: Glady :D Tnx mate... for subject_tbl additional entries should be: **`INSERT INTO subject_tbl 
 (`subject_id`, `subject_name`, `subject_yr`, `subject_sem`)
VALUES
 (2002, 'Math', 2011, '1st'),
 (2003, 'Science', 2011, '1st'),
 (2004, 'History', 2011, '1st'),
 (2005, 'PE', 2011, '1st'),
    (2006, 'Social Studies', 2011, '1st'),
 (2007, 'Math', 2011, '2nd'),
 (2008, 'Science', 2011, '2nd'),
 (2009, 'History', 2011, '2nd'),
 (2010, 'PE', 2011, '2nd'),
    (2011, 'Social Studies', 2011, '2nd')
;`**

Comment: same subjects but different semesters and school years :D

Comment: Yup. Still referring the student's subjects taken and what he missed during that school term.

Comment: is `SUBJECT_ID` needed on the result? do you have any unique constraint on table `subject_tbl`?

Comment: yup. its like saying i want to echo the specific subject with its ID,NAME,SEMESTER,SCHOOL YEAR.

Comment: whoa lots of examples :D tnx again mate ur a life saver... ill look into it right away.

Comment: this tells that the student is missing this subjects right? :D